# Odd sample size in GPower (Repeated Measures ANOVA, within factor)

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, sample-size, gpower

I am going to conduct a pretty simple experiment: one within factor with 8 levels for a single group of participants.
I'm trying to determine the apporpriate sample size using GPower based on an effect size of eta square = 0.60 from a previous study.

However, the end sample size is odd. Here are the parameters I entered :

> F tests > ANOVA: Repeated measures, within factors > A priori
>
> Effect size = 0.6 => (f = 1.2247449)
>
> alpha = 0.05 / Power = 0.80
>
> Number of groups = 1
>
> Number of measurements = 8
>
> Corr among measures = 0.5
>
> Nonsphericity correction = 1

Result : a sample size of only 2 participants.

What exactly is the problem with my input? Is there another way to compute the appropriate sample size?